# is "modus operandi" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

Is the phrase (as used in English) "modus operandi" singular or plural?  And if the former, what is its plural form [or vice versa]?

(To my untutored eye, "modus" seems to be a singular form, while "operandi" seems to be a plural.)

A search of this site does not reveal anything bearing on the matter.

Comment: Had you done sufficient but simple research, you would not have needed to ask the question, Plural = modi operandorum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi

Comment: @BlessedGeek: I have to keep spamming people here, but *operandorum* is wrong. The plural is *modi operandi*: *operandi* is just a word in the genitive that doesn't change. "One mode of operation, two modes of operation" (not "two modes of operations").  We don't say *a way of life, different ways of lives*, do we? Besides, in Latin, you absolutely cannot pluralise a gerundium, and *operandi* is a gerundium. You can pluralise a gerundivum, but that is very uncommon in the genitive; and this isn't a gerundivum, even though gerundium and neuter gerundivum have the same form.

Comment: All of the answers seem basically to give the Latin plural. But the phrase is now an English phrase. I'd be interested to read an answer giving what the most natural English plural form would be.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I'm not sure why you would give a reference that contradicts rather than supports your claim. Perhaps you are withholding evidence?

Comment: @CanisLupus: I edited the Wikipaedia article after he had posted that.

Comment: @Cerberus :( Now I have lost all confidence in the internet. There is nothing left.

Comment: @CanisLupus: Aww Wikipaedia is just never perfect, but it's still good for many things.

Answer (score 7):

*Modus operandi* is singular in both Latin and English. The plural is *modi operandi*, and, judging from [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modi%20operandi%2Cmodus%20operandis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmodi%20operandi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmodus%20operandis%3B%2Cc0), I would advise against *modus operandis*.

Since there seems to be some confusion over why only *modus* changes form in the plural, but never *operandi*, I'll explain that too.

*Modus* is the most important word here, quite clearly meaning *mode*. It's a noun and nouns are simple. The plural is *modi*.

*Operandi* is rather more complex. We may translate it as *of operation*, but that's not very precise: *mode of operation* would be *modus operationis*. More exactly, *operandi* means *of operating*. It's a gerund, which can't be pluralized either in Latin or in English. However many times you've gone fishing, you'll still say that you like fishing, never that you like fishings. It's the same in Latin.

The confusion arises because the Latin gerund shares its singular forms with the gerundive, which can be pluralized. We know that *modus operandi* does not use the gerundive because then it would mean *mode of something to be performed*, which is rather nonsensical. So, I'd strongly advise against using *modi operandorum*, since I presume you don't mean *modes of things to be performed* - nor am I particularly sure what anyone might mean by it.

You might say that, if people used *modus operandorum* often enough, then using it would be fair game. You'd be right. Luckily for us, however, [Ngrams doesn't have a single instance of it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modi%20operandorum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

Comment: The Ngram search engine isn't perfect. Here are [books listed by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modi+operandorum%22&num=50&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=k_oYVdLoLYHXgwTyrIDYAg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=839) that include *modi operandorum*.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps a discussion about what type of act should be done next in the Vatican operatic society might meaningfully talk about a _modus operandorum_ ‘form of things to be opera’ed’…

Comment: @WS2 I'm sorry for Ninja-editing Wikipaedia on you. I didn't mean it the way it looks, but I just had to correct the article when I saw it.

Comment: @Mike Playing devil's advocate... The phrase is originally Latin, but has been co-opted into English. So, if everyone started using "modi operandorum", it'd become correct English by definition. In the same way that so much of English is already terrible Latin, this would be a drop in the proverbial bucket. The N-gram viewer sees all...

Comment: @ParthianShot: Hello, fellow underworldling. That would be "correct" using a definition not many people would want to write by. In other words, if "correct" just means "what many people do", then it has lost all meaning. Then say "many people do this" rather than applying a judgement of value like "correct". In my inferior (get it?) opinion, most people who ask for writing advice want to write in a nice way, abiding by more rules than the absolute minimum.

Comment: @Anonym, Gerunds **can** be pluralized. The working of X. The workings of X.

Comment: @Pacerier Perhaps sometimes, although it's doubtful whether your example is actually a gerund or rather a verbal noun, which often takes the same form and can be pluralized. At any rate, the Latin gerund has no plural ever.

Answer (score 3):

It is **singular**. The plural form is *modi operandi* (modes of operation). See where it says *plural* in [Merriam-Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modus%20operandi), [Dictionary.com's](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/modus%20operandi), and [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi) entries.

---

Of note,  *modi operandorum* (modes of operations) is never correct, as plural gerundiums are an impossibility in Latin[1][2].

---

Sources:

[1] See comments to this answer made by Cerberus, a scholar in the field.

[2] See [this page](http://www.dl.ket.org/latinlit/grammar/gerund.htm) on gerunds in Latin.

Comment: *Operandorum* is wrong. The plural is *modi operandi*: *operandi* is just a word in the genitive that doesn't change upon pluralisation. "One mode of operation, two modes of operation" (not "two modes of operations"). We don't say *a way of life, different ways of lives*, do we?

Comment: @Cerberus, of course there can be "multiple modes of operations", if referring to multiple operations, each of which have multiple modes.

Comment: Sure, that is possible; but *modes of operations* is not the plural of *mode of operation*, but it is the plural of *mode of operations*, which is something else (and something rather odd to boot).

Comment: Also, why are we definitively applying intricacies of English grammar to Latin?

Comment: That was just an illustration, because in this case English happens to work much the same way as Latin.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how can you be certain that the same English rule applies to Latin? Also, *modes of operations* is still a pluralization of *mode of operation*.

Comment: @Mike the question is asking about the other way round: how do we know Latin rules apply to English?

Comment: @Mike: I have studied Latin in school and at university and as a job for two decades, so I know how it works. Your latest edit has improved your answer, but **modi operandorum* is still impossible in Latin. // I see what you mean, but I still don't think *modes of operations* is the plural of *mode of operation*, but of *mode of operations*. One bag of tea, two bags of tea. One bag of teas means something else (now there are suddenly several kinds of tea inside the bag, or something), and its plural two bags of teas does, too.

Comment: Of course, I agree the meanings are different. But I leave it to the OP to choose the most suitable pluralization for their specific case. Any way you cut it, it's still a valid pluralization of *mode of operation*, though. It's just pluraler than the alternative.  =)

Comment: The biggest problem here is that *operandi* is a gerund, which can't even be pluralized. The tricky part is that the gerund shares many forms with the gerundive, which can be. *Modi operandorum* means *methods of things to be performed*.

Comment: @Anonym, do you have a source showing that operandi *cannot* be pluralized? Because a number of online sources show that it can.

Comment: Mike, your own links don't mention _modi operandorum_ as a plural.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, Ha! Good catch! It looks like Cerberus went in and [modified the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Modus_operandi&action=history).

Comment: You can see *modi operandorum* being used in [various books listed by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22modi+operandorum%22&num=50&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=k_oYVdLoLYHXgwTyrIDYAg&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=839).

Comment: @Mike: Pluralising a gerundium is impossible. If you really need a source, here it is: http://apps.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/advanced/lesson11/ *"It is active in meaning and only exists in the singular form."* It even mentions *modus operandi*.

Comment: @Cerberus, *callings*, *readings*, etc., can all have 's' at the end. "The callings of priests" (signifying singular callings for each priest). "The readings of their palms" (signifying multiple individual readings). Gerunds being singular is usually true, but it's not a hard-and-fast rule. It depends on the context, of course.

Comment: @Mike: It is not possible in Latin, hence my "gerundium".

Comment: @Mike Any source claiming that Latin gerunds can be plural has probably confused them with gerundives. Nor can the English gerund be plural. Your examples share the gerund's form, but are in fact verbal nouns.

Comment: @Anonym: That does depend on your definition: if you define gerunds the narrow way, then those aren't gerunds.

Answer (score 2):

It is a singular phrase.   The plural form being "modi operandi".

You can find more about it at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modus%20operandi) and [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modus+operandi)

> - modus operandi - "A method of operating or functioning, a person's manner of working. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/modus+operandi)

Answer (score 1):

Modus operandi = the method of operating. (Plural:  modi  operandi ,  but NOT modi operandorum which is the genitive plural of the gerundive, not of the gerund. As others have said, you cannot pluralize a gerund in Latin. Otherwise in this case it would be of operatings, which is a nonsense.)

**However**:  using the Latin noun for operation (*operatio, operationis*), as far as I know, you could have mode of operation, modes of operation, or mode of operations or modes of operations; each of the four being a slightly different concept. This could be achieved using the genitive of the noun *operatio*: that is genitive singular = *operationis*; and genitive plural *operationem*. Thus the four different possibilities would be *modus operationis* (mode of operation), *modi   operationis* (modes of operation), *modus operationem* (mode of operations) and   *modi   operationem* (modes of operations). Does that make sense? But wouldn't it be far easier just to say it in English?